# JSON 2 POJO offline

Tags: java, json, maven, pojo

I would like to generate a Java object from JSON. All examples on the Internet use an ObjectMapper class and a Java class to serialize the JSON too.

The JSON is complicated, and I don't want to define the Java class by hand with annotations for properties.

I want to be able to generate the Java class with Jackson or GSON annotations with the JSON data with software.

The website jsonschema2pojo does this for you online. My JSON is offline in a private network where I cannot use jsonschema2pojo for a complicated JSON string.

How can I replicate the jsonschema2pojo code in my own environment? Is it easy to do with Jackson, or GSON?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Jackson or GSON have this support yet but lots of people have contributed code according to your requirement.

You can check:

https://github.com/astav/JsonToJava
or
https://github.com/wotifgroup/json2pojo

Moreover maybe you can try downloading that dependent jar manually and add it in your MAVEN repository manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonschema2pojo offline. It can be used as a Maven plugin, a Gradle plugin, and command line tool or an Ant task.

At the bottom of the page at [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) you'll see links to help with each of these methods.